# sending data from controller to view in zend framework 2

Tags: php, view, controller, zend-framework2

It might be a easy but I'm  new on this.

I'm trying to write a simple post & category system. I created an category module, and also post module.

I want to add selectbox for select which category of this to addpost page. I dont know how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check out this tutorials http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288420/949273 it's cover basic of ZF2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing values to view in Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331792/passing-values-to-view-in-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 1):

you just have to inject the resultset in your form and make an array with to pass it in select options.

```
<?php
namespace Mylib\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Mylib\Form\MyForm;

class MyControler extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $myObjectTable;

    public function getMyObjectTable(){
        if(!$this->myObjectTable){
            $this->myObjectTable = $this->getServiceLocator()
                ->get('MyLib\Model\MyObjectTable');
        }
    }

    public function indexAction(){
        $objects = $this->getMyObjectTable()->fetchall();

        $form = new MyForm($objects);

        $filter = new MyFormFilter();
        $form->setInputFilter($filter->getInputFilter());

        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if($form->isValid()){
            // [...] here the post treatment
        }
        return array('form' =>$form);
    }
}
```

and in your form :

```
<?php
namespace Mylib\Form;

class MyForm
{
    public function __construct($objects){
        $selectOptions = array();
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $selectOptions[$object->id]=$object->thePropertyIWantToList;
        }
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'object_id',
            'type' => 'Select',
            'options' => array(
                'value_options' => $selectOptions,
                'label' => 'MySelectBoxLabel',
            )
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 9, // to select a default value
            )
        ));
        //and the rest of the form... 
         $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'value' => 'Go',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```